# Marketing Cloud Push won't increment the badge no in iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I am getting issues with Badge count on IOS. When I send the push notification via ET, (And yes I picked 'yes' to increment badge count in iOS)it always set the badge attribute in payload as '1'. Because of that application badge count won't increase. (When app is in the killed state)

Is there any method that we should invoke once we receive a push message to the app so that ET knows that it has to increase the badge count?

JB4A SDK Version in use : 4.9.5.20

Appreciate your help regarding this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected SDK behavior. I'll make a note to ensure that the web interface is clarified.

In 4.9.5 and later, badges are now set according to the following logic:

- If a push message is sent, badge is set to 1 + number of unread Inbox messages
- If an inbox message is added, the badge is set to the number of unread Inbox messages (via silent push if available)
- when the app goes to the background, the badge is set to the number of locally-calculated unread inbox messages